# Injecting a variable from v-for into a value for on-click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently using a mixture of VueJS & PHP in my Application and before when I used AngularJS I was able to do it this way.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is make my anchor call a javascript method on click. Now the problem is that I don't want it to call a method inside my Vue app as the method will be stored outside. So my question is if there's anyway I can simply do something like

`onclick="function('value', '{{ for.id }}')`

instead of doing it like so

`v-on:click(somefunction($for.id)`

Comment: so you want to use a function not inside vuejs method but using vue's v-on directive?

Comment: Why not call a vue method that then calls the outside function (i.e. the vue method wraps the JS function call)?

Comment: I'm slightly mentally challenged, do you mind showing like an example of what you mean if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue has complete control over the HTML generated for a Vue component, and in many situations parts of the template will be regenerated by Vue (in response to things like `v-if`, `v-for` etc), so you can't really use "classic" `onclick` function handlers, you must use `v-on` to call a method defined within the component. From inside that method you can then call any global function you want.

```js
function external(item) {
  alert('You clicked ' + item);
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
  },
  methods: {
    internal(item) {
      // Delegate to external function
      external(item);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-for="item of items" @click="internal(item)">{{ item }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While this actually had an answer for a question that I was going to ask later. I did realize my issue, I was trying to debug curious as to why I couldn't even see the "onclick" line in my thing from the beginning. But it just seems to be a feature with Vue so there was actually nothing wrong with my code from the get-go.